# Company officer

Tags: word-choice

I saw in an app the word in Japanese is kaishain, but when I looked up in dictionary, it said shain. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

会社員 would be used to indicate the type of job you're in. 
Categories could be professor (教員), doctor (医師), nurse (看護師), public services (公務員) and so on.

社員 would be used to indicate that you are an employee from a said private company.
トヨタ社員 for example, if you work for Toyota.

Answer (score 6):

社員 (*shain*) is used to refer to a member of a certain company. 会社員 (*kaishain*) is a job name.

- 「仕事は何ですか？」「会社員です。」
  "What do you do?"　"I'm an office worker."
- 会社員をやめて店を開いています。
  I'm running a shop after leaving a company.
- XYZ社の社員となった。
  I became a member of XYZ company.
- うちの会社には社員が50人います。
  There are 50 members in my company.